# How to import JSON to Excel correctly

Tags: json, excel, vba

My objective is to run a search for some data and return the results into an excel table. I'm using the service newsapi.org and using VBA to do this.

I'm sending a XMLHttpRequest to newsapi.org and successfully receiving a (JSON) response, which I am able to save into a file on my desktop. I however cannot import that response into excel as I receive run-time error 13: type mismatch.

Bizarrely when I change my source to a different JSON file, it works. e.g. http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

So I'm assuming the issue is somewhere around the type of the JSON response I am receiving.

```
Public Sub xmlhttptutorial()

Dim xmlhttp As Object
Dim myurl As String
Dim JSON As Object
Dim myFile As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
Set ws = Sheet2
myFile = "C:\Users\A0781525\Desktop\myFile.txt"
myurl = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=Ashley%20Madison%20Data%20Breach&"
xmlhttp.Open "GET", myurl, False
xmlhttp.Send
Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(xmlhttp.ResponseText)
Open myFile For Output As #1: Print #1, xmlhttp.ResponseText: Close #1
i = 2
For Each Item In JSON
    Range("A2").Value = Item("articles")("0:")("source")("id:")
    Range("A2").Value = Item("articles")("0:")("source")("name")
    Range("A2").Value = Item("articles")("0:")("title")
i = i + 1
Next
End Sub
```

The break occurs at line:
`Range("A2").Value = Item("articles")("0:")("source")("id:")`

A sample of the JSON file output I receive:

{"status":"ok","totalResults":16,"articles":[{"source":{"id":"mashable","name":"Mashable"},"author":"Jack Morse","title":"Porn site leaks over a million users' private info","description":"The great thing about the internet is that no one has to know you have a serious thing for hentai pornography. Unless, that is, the porn site you have an account on leaks your personal information. Over a million Luscious.net account holders faced that unexpe…","url":"https://mashable.com/article/porn-site-leaks-users-data/","urlToImage":"https://mondrian.mashable.com/2019%252F08%252F20%252F24%252F62fc9aa277d54b2092a39393d2202a62.856fe.jpg%252F1200x630.jpg?signature=MBXieHs3n4uvowiVyV4K8cCO4j4=","publishedAt":"2019-08-20T22:36:24Z","content":"The great thing about the internet is that no one has to know you have a serious thing for hentai pornography. Unless, that is, the porn site you have an account on leaks your personal information. \r\nOver a million Luscious.net account holders faced that unex… [+2840 chars]"}

Comment: Are you sure your request gets the correct response? I'm getting an error saying that my APIKey is missing. Do you have an API key? If so, shouldn't you include it somehow in your request?

Comment: Yeah I am getting the same error

Comment: @StavrosJon Yes I have an API key - I removed it from the code above for confidentiality reasons. I get A response back that includes all the correct information and looks like a JSON.

Comment: I've also had to download and install the "JsonConverter" dictionary you see above

Comment: If you printed out `xmlhttp.ResponseText` and it is what you expect it to be then you're probably parsing it the wrong way. Can you update your post with a snippet of the json so we can see its structure? I suspect this `("0:")` is what's wrong and it should be just `(1)`.

Comment: @jank ...or even just ("0") or something like that.

Comment: Post the actual JSON file you are receiving (in text; not as a screenshot), else troubleshooting will be nigh impossible.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld see above

Comment: @stavrosjon see above JSON output

Comment: @jank Try what I suggested above. It should be `(1)` instead of `("0:")` because `articles` is an array.

Comment: @stavrosjon tried that but same error. I'm guessing that a "type mismatch" error would suggest that the _Range("A2").Value_ type is mismatching the JSON? Should I change it something else?

Comment: @jank try this `debug.print JSON("articles")(1)("source")("id")` for example. The `For-Each part` is problematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are parsing the JSON incorrectly. Probably due to a misunderstanding of how it is constructed.

Try something like:

```
i = 2
'Cells.Clear
For Each item In JSON("articles")
    Cells(i, 1).Value = item("source")("id")
    Cells(i, 2).Value = item("source")("name")
    Cells(i, 3).Value = item("title")
i = i + 1
Next
```

Comment: You beat me to it :D Discarding my post

Comment: @RonRosenfeld works a charm. Thanks so much! How did you know that that was the issue?

Comment: @jank You can make use of the `Locals` and `Watch` windows to examine the various elements of the JSON.  Some can be dictionary objects; some may be collections.  You can also examine the JSON string itself once you understand how they are built.  Look at the `[...]` and `{...}` elements to differentiate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the way you are trying to access the parsed json elements.

Not having the exact structure of the JSON the best I can do is assume what you need to do is this:

```
Debug.Print JSON("articles")(1)("source")("id")
```

To access the first article's id.

or this

```
For Each item In JSON("articles")
Debug.Print item("source")("id")
Next item
```

to loop through them